# trigger socket.emit with a button click

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to do a little app chat but I can't get put it to work

In my `app.js`:

```
var io = require('./io');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

io.on('error', function () {
    console.log("errr");
});
```

`chat.js`:

```
$(() => {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');  

    $("#sendMessage").click(function () { 
        alert("click")
        socket.emit("news", { message: $("#message").val() })
    });

    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log("test"+data);
    });
})
```

The socket.emit that is in app.js works, I get the info on the chat.js but I don't know why, the socket.on is not receiving the message from the button click. The button works because the alert is displayed but nothing is emitted. Any ideas?

Comment: you are emitting messages (front client app) to `news` event, but listening (on the server) only `my other event` event. Try to change `my other event` -> `news`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are emitting messages (front client app) to `news`, but listening (on the server) only `my other event`.

Try:

```
var io = require('./io');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});

    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);

        // Depends on your business logic

        // Sends to sender-client only      
        // socket.emit('news', data);

        // Sends to all clients except sender
        // socket.broadcast.emit('news', data);

        // Sends to all client including sender     
        io.emmit('news', data);
    });
});

io.on('error', function () {
    console.log("errr");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code might solve your issue:

```
var io = require('./io');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', {hello: 'world'});
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});

io.on('error', function () {
    console.log("errr");
});
```